# .htaccess error with multiple rewriterules

Tags: ssl, .htaccess

I'm having a bit of an issue with my .htaccess file. I recently got an SSL certificate for my website and the https:// is working perfectly. However, I wanted to redirect any traffic using http:// to the new https://, but there seems to be an conflict with a previous rule I have.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
# 404 Document Location
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
# Turning Redirects On
RewriteEngine On
# Redirection from HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# Redirection for filenames ending in .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Basically, the first redirection is supposed to be moving people from http:// to https://, the second is the one I previously had to truncate filetypes from the end of a domain (e.g. /cv.html is just /cv).

Can anyone see the conflict and let me know how to sort it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I think you might have to call that rule the last one, and then do the suffixing on the next visit when https is there.